# rails bundler version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have rails project working on Ubuntu.
Now I installed WSL on another machine and cloned the very same project.
Now when I try to install bundler with

```
gem install bundler
```

it installed bundler 2.0.2 and on `bundle install` it gives error:

**Could not find gem 'bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (~> 5.0.0)'**

Now I looked at the gemfile.lock it was bundled with 1.16.4, I installed it with

```
 gem install bundler -v '1.16.4'
```

Now I do a simple `bundle install`, then it uses 2.0.2, so I have to do

```
bundle _1.16.4_ install
```

It completed successfully, but now when I am trying to do `rails db:create`, it says

**The git source https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application**

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall bundler 2.0.2:

```
gem uninstall bundler -v 2.0.2
```

If you still have problem, you can use:

```
bundle exec rails db:create
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update to using bundler 2.x if possible with:

```
bundle update --bundler
```

This will change the `BUNDLED_WITH` version in Gemfile.lock.

see: https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html

You could also set the default bundler version:

```
bundler config default 1.16.4
gem list bundler
```

However I have found this to be a bit error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all your gems (go to the gems folder of your ruby, remove the specifications folder and the gems folder),

- `gem list` should be more or less empty
- `gem install bundler`
- And try to `bundle install` again from scratch.